# Update parent record on add/save of child

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a parent model, "Project" which hasMany "Risks" When I update (add/edit/delete) a Risk, I'd like to also update the parent Project's Updated field.

This works (in the RisksController):

```
if ($this->Risk->save($this->request->data)) {
    $this->loadModel('Project');
    $project = $this->Project->findById($this->request->data['Risk']['project_id']);
    $this->Project->id = $project['Project']['id'];
    $this->Project->saveField('Updated', time());
...
```

But there HAS to be an easier way.

Comment: Since Project hasMany Risk, Risk probably _belongsTo_ Project. If so, you do not have to loadModel, since the association is already defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$this->Risk->saveAssociated($this->request-data)` for this.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way would be to use the [afterSave](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#aftersave) callback.

It would be almost the same code you have (I think you should App::uses instead of loadModel)

Another way would be a mysql trigger but that is not easier than this one.